# What's the subject? "You telling me that is galling."

Tags: possessives

Reading other questions, a sentence from this question, [A single word for "hurting of one's pride"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247288/a-single-word-for-hurting-of-ones-pride), caught my eyes.

> You telling me that my question asking abilities are poor is very galling.

I guess this sentence has no problem, as there's no mention about this on the page, but I cannot be sure of what the subject of this sentence is. Since, *you* has a form of subject pronoun and the following clause, *telling me...*, works as a participle clause, it seems *you* would be the subject. However, if *you* is the subject, the verb should be *are*.

Furthermore, the sentence's meaning is that the fact that you're telling me such thing is galling, not that you are galling. So, I think *you* should be possessive *your*.

Which one should I use here: *you* or *your*?

Comment: For a second there i thought someone had done a very thourough edit on my post. Then i saw you just mentioned it. But I think Luke is right, I will change the title to please the grammar sticklers out there:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject is the noun phrase:

> You telling me that my question asking abilities are poor

Where the crucial noun is the gerund *telling*.

Some grammar sticklers would say that for this to be correct it would have to read *Your telling...*

Comment: I'm not the most hidebound of sticklers, but I think that "Your telling me..." would feel a bit more natural.

Comment: Also, If this answer doesn't quite make sense to the asker, I would also note that "Your telling me..." can be replaced with other noun phrases, such as "Your statement that my question asking abilities are poor" or "Your criticism of my question asking abilities". When it's rewritten with a word that's not a gerund, it's hopefully quite clear which noun is the subject, as you've located it.

Comment: In that sentence, _telling_ is a verb, not a noun. Gerunds are verbs that head clauses that **act** as nouns; but they're not nouns themselves. Nouns, for instance, can't take direct and indirect objects like _telling_ does; but verbs can.

Comment: There's no reason why _your_ has to be used as subject of a gerund clause, btw; `POSS`-_ing_ , which produces _your telling_, is indeed one of the two gerund complementizers of English; the other one is `ACC`-_ing_, which produces _you telling_ instead. Both are correct; there is no grammatical difference, and like the _for..to_ complementizer for infinitives, or the _then_ complementizer for _if..then_ constructions, there is a vast amount of optional variation and deletion. Executive summary: The possessive is no longer required; it's optional.

Comment: @JohnLawler I see that *you telling..* is also grammatically correct in the sense that *you* is accusative. But, can accusatives be subjects? I mean, accusatives--as far as I'm aware--aren't they kind of objectives? Isn't it wrong for objects to be subjects?